# I am not able to read the license file for Digital signature using eparaksts

Tags: maven, spring-boot, digital-signature

We are creating an API which will read a PDf file and automatically sign and validate the PDF using the Digital card. I have added license file in config folder. I dont know how to read that file using Spring boot Maven

```
16:54:39.929 [main] DEBUG lv.eparaksts.conf.A - resolveResource: try configKey: eparaksts.license
16:54:39.945 [main] DEBUG lv.eparaksts.conf.A - resolveResource: try systemPropertyKey: eparaksts.properties.url
16:54:39.946 [main] DEBUG lv.eparaksts.conf.A - resolveResource: try resourceName: /eparaksts.properties
16:54:39.946 [main] WARN lv.eparaksts.conf.A - The configuration file is missing!
16:54:39.948 [main] DEBUG lv.eparaksts.conf.A - resolveResource: try systemPropertyKey: edoc.properties.url
16:54:39.948 [main] DEBUG lv.eparaksts.conf.A - resolveResource: try resourceName: /edoc.properties
16:54:39.948 [main] WARN lv.eparaksts.conf.A - The configuration file is missing!
16:54:39.953 [main] DEBUG lv.eparaksts.conf.A - -- 0 keys #Wed Nov 29 16:54:39 IST 2017

16:54:39.954 [main] DEBUG lv.eparaksts.conf.A - resolveResource: try systemPropertyKey: eparaksts.license.url
16:54:39.954 [main] DEBUG lv.eparaksts.conf.A - resolveResource: try resourceName: /eparaksts.license
16:54:39.954 [main] DEBUG lv.eparaksts.conf.A - resolveResource: try configKey: edoc.license
16:54:39.954 [main] DEBUG lv.eparaksts.conf.A - resolveResource: try systemPropertyKey: edoc.license.url
16:54:39.954 [main] DEBUG lv.eparaksts.conf.A - resolveResource: try resourceName: /edoc.license
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load eParaksts Java Libraries license!
 at lv.eparaksts.conf.A.I(ConfigPrivate.java:653)
 at lv.eparaksts.conf.A.F(ConfigPrivate.java:560)
 at lv.eparaksts.conf.A.K(ConfigPrivate.java:546)
 at lv.eparaksts.edoc.EDoc2Builder.newEDoc(EDoc2Builder.java:63)
 at lv.eparaksts.edoc.EDoc2Builder.newEDoc(EDoc2Builder.java:52)
 at com.narola.lv.eparaksts.sample.EDoc2Sample.main(EDoc2Sample.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The eParaksts Java Libraries license file is missing!
 at lv.eparaksts.conf.A.I(ConfigPrivate.java:624)
 ... 5 more
16:54:39.957 [main] ERROR lv.eparaksts.conf.A - The eParaksts Java Libraries license file is missing!
java.lang.RuntimeException: The eParaksts Java Libraries license file is missing!
 at lv.eparaksts.conf.A.I(ConfigPrivate.java:624)
 at lv.eparaksts.conf.A.F(ConfigPrivate.java:560)
 at lv.eparaksts.conf.A.K(ConfigPrivate.java:546)
 at lv.eparaksts.edoc.EDoc2Builder.newEDoc(EDoc2Builder.java:63)
 at lv.eparaksts.edoc.EDoc2Builder.newEDoc(EDoc2Builder.java:52)
 at com.narola.lv.eparaksts.sample.EDoc2Sample.main(EDoc2Sample.java:60)
Finished
```

Where shall I keep the license file.

Comment: Did you read the related documentation? It's probably explained

Comment: Its resolved . I had added the config folder in my dependencies.

Comment: Well done. Maybe you can post your own answer explaining how you did solve your issue so it can help others ;)